# How to control location refresh inteval?

Tags: android, location, refresh, intervals

I have only one question: How to control `.setInterval`, `.setFastestInterval`, `.setSmallestAmount` in this code, with button click for example?

```
 protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(10);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }
```

I am calling this method from `OnCreate()`;

Comment: Are you looking at http://javapapers.com/android/android-location-fused-provider/

Comment: That link you posted does not explain how to change those values, which was my only question...

Comment: I was asking if that is where you got that code snippet from? It would be easier to answer if we knew the full context of that code.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how much it will help you. But may be some other guy might get help from here.
I have written a tutorial about using googleapiclient's location service. You can look into it. 
https://androidtutorialmagic.wordpress.com/2015/01/15/update-location-by-using-googleapiclient-in-android-tutorial/

```
mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
```

This two line above might help you whatever you wanted.

Comment: Look at my question, I want to CHANGE those intervals with click of a button. Not just set to whatever value, but let user to change them.

Comment: You can do that by taking the value in a variable and set it there.